# Regex - how to test for 2 str patterns and make replacements based on which str pattern matches

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I currently have two functioning separate subs in Excel VBA.  Each sub searches for a different string pattern and then makes a replacement.

Sub 1 searches for a leading 0 in the target string, strips it out, and places the contents in a separate cell.

Sub 2 searches for terminal "99" in the target string, replacing the "99" with Xs, and places the contents in a separate cell.

The way I do this particular operation is to run Sub1 first. Results are placed in column AO.  Then I run Sub2 against the results obtained from Sub1 and place those results in the next adjacent column.

I would like to combine the two subs and run just one time getting the desired results.

Here are examples of the target string in column W that I am applying the regex against:

```
098765-9876-77
333222-7777-G5
9876-078-99
9867x77A
```

Sub 1

```
Sub tom_briggs_test_leading_zero()
'This sub searches for a leading zero in the target string and removes it.

Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("w2:w73352")

For Each cell In Myrange
    strPattern = "^0(.*)"
    If strPattern <> "" Then
    strInput = cell.Value
    strReplace = "$1"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        cell.Offset(0, 18) = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)

    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 18) = strInput
    End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Sub 2

```
Sub tom_briggs_test_trailing_99()
'This sub searchs for teriminal 99s in the target string and replaces them 
'with -XX.

Dim regEx As New RegExp
Dim strPattern As String
Dim strInput As String
Dim strReplace As String
Dim Myrange As Range

Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("AO2:AO73352")
'AO is the column where results from Sub1 have been placed

For Each cell In Myrange
    strPattern = "(.*)-99$"
    If strPattern <> "" Then
    strInput = cell.Value
    strReplace = "$1-XX"

    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
        cell.Offset(0, 1) = regEx.Replace(strInput, strReplace)

    Else
        cell.Offset(0, 1) = strInput
    End If
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
Sub tom_briggs_fix_head_and_tail()
    'This sub removes a leading zero in the target string and
    'replaces trailing 99s in the target string with -XX.

    Dim regExHead As New RegExp
    Dim strHeadPattern As String
    Dim strHeadReplace As String

    Dim regExTail As New RegExp
    Dim strTailPattern As String
    Dim strTailReplace As String

    Dim strInput As String
    Dim Myrange As Range
    Dim c As Range

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("w2:w73352")
    strHeadPattern = "^0(.*)"
    strHeadReplace = "$1"
    strTailPattern = "(.*)-99$"
    strTailReplace = "$1-XX"

    With regExHead
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strHeadPattern
    End With

    With regExTail
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strTailPattern
    End With

    For Each c In Myrange
        strInput = c.Value
        strInput = IIf(regExHead.Test(strInput), _
                regExHead.Replace(strInput, strHeadReplace), strInput)
        strInput = IIf(regExTail.Test(strInput), _
                regExTail.Replace(strInput, strTailReplace), strInput)
        c.Offset(0, 19) = strInput
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Comment: #xidgel - your code is exactly what I needed.  I will learn from your assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a regex for that. Just take a hint from the following code:

```
    Sub test()
    Set myRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:A2")     'Change this range as per your requirement
    For Each cell In myRange
        strInput = cell.Value
        'Checking if the 1st number is 0 or not
        If CInt(Mid(strInput, 1, 1)) = 0 Then
            strInput = Mid(strInput, 2)
        End If
        'Checking if -99 is present in the end or not
        If StrComp("-99", Right(strInput, 3), 1) = 0 Then
            strInput = Left(strInput, Len(strInput) - 3) & "-XX"
        End If
        'If there was a leading 0 or a trailing 99, then only write the updated value in another cell   
        If StrComp(cell.Value, strInput, 1) <> 0 Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = strInput
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: My apologies.  I should have mentioned that the data in column W is classified as text. I have edited the posted question to show several examples of the target text.  I tried the code from the posted answer and couldn't get it to provide the results.